# set text in TextView in Handler bad performance

Tags: android, performance, datepicker, textview

As Android does not support showing the day for a date, I added a TextView to my layout.

On the DatePicker I put an onDateChangedListener. When the date changes, I determine the day of the week and then set it via a Handler to be sure it is done on the UI thread:

```
// this is being called when the date changes on the DatePicker
public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, final int year,
                final int monthOfYear, final int dayOfMonth) {
    String dayOfTheWeek = null;

    // some code here to set the 'dayOfTheWeek' string

    h.sendMessage(h.obtainMessage(0, dayOfTheWeek));
}

final Handler h = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        dayOfWeekTextView.setText((String)msg.obj);
    }
};
```

My issue: when I scroll through the days in the widget ([Android 4.0 U](http://www.antetype.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Datepicker.png)I) it is not smooth! I check what the problem was, and it is not the way I determine what the String should be, it is really the `setText()` in the Handler. Commenting that part uit and everything is ok. Also setting a hardcoded text there (`dayOfWeekTextView.setText("SOMETHING');`) gives the same problem. It jitters the `DatePicker`.

Is `setText()` really that big of an action? Wunderlist shows the day of the week and there it runs smooth, but I just cannot find out how they do it.

I have only tested it on my `HTC One X`.
Anyone an idea?

> Edit:
>
> I found out why it is smooth in Wunderlist! I am using the same as them, a DialogFragment. You can set a title on the dialog and that is what Wunderlist uses instead of a TextView. So I'm going to use that (and looks better too ;) )
>
> So when doing 'getDialog().setTitle(dayOfWeek)' there is no problem. Still the question remains: how come the setText is that slow on the UI thread...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLUTION**
A very sexy and dirty solution would be to create 7 `TextView`s and toggle the visibility of one of them. Until the day that a week is extended to 8 days, this approach should work with much better performance.

---

On a separate note, this might be due to the layout params of your textview. You might want to give it some extra space, or, in other words, a layout should not be incurred by setText. Am not sure if that is happening.

Comment: Yes, this is a possibility, but not the answer to my question. Thanks for your proposed solution, I do appreciate it. So you think it might be the layout params? So (I cannot check now, at my dayjob ;) ) I might need to check if layout_width is set to match_parent?

Comment: Yep, maybe match_parent will not induce a redraw to the whole heirarchy

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was indeed 'match_parent' what did the trick! And I learned a new word (incurred) :)

Answer (score 4):

The bad performance may be a result of a recalculation of the layout.  If the textview width is wrap-content, then every time the text changes, the layout is updated.
Try fixing the width of the textview.

Answer (score 0):

try this format:

```
t1.setText(""+string_name);
```

I used this format for setting the Text in both TextView and EditText

Comment: this will actually be slower (or the same in best case) as `(String)msg.obj`. the `msg.obj` is already of type `String` so no conversion is necessary.

Comment: When I'm trying this format setText(str_name), it didn't work for me. That's why i used setText(""+str_name) and it works fine for me

Comment: Yes, I tried it (not understanding how an extra step would speed it up). What do you mean 'it didn't work for me' ? Performance wise or it just didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I tried implement the same using the similar 'handler' approach you stated and turns out it 
works pretty great n responsive too.

Try this code:

```
final DatePicker dp = (DatePicker)findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);

        dp.init(2012, 6, 17, new OnDateChangedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                    final int dayOfMonth) {

                handler.post(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

                        // some code here to set the 'dayOfTheWeek' string


                        tv.setText(Integer.toString(dayOfTheWeek));   // (if you want to set a number of day instead of its name)

                                           //  OR

                        tv.setText(dayOfTheWeek);   

                    }
                });

            }
        });
```

The catch here is to use the Wrapper class **Integer** to convert the int value to a String. If you pass the '**plane int**', it will throw a **Resource Not Found** exception.

Comment: I think you used 'match_parent' for the width, this fixed it for me (and I'm going to set that as the answer). Thanks anyway for your effort to post an answer!